# Fill missing days in timeseries (with duplicate keys)

Tags: python, pandas

Here is what I'm trying to do in Pandas:

- load CSV file containing information about stocks for certain days
- find the earliest and latest dates in the column `date`
- create a new dataframe where all the days between the earliest and latest are filled (NaN or something like "missing" for all columns would be fine)

Currently it looks like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import dateutil

df = pd.read_csv("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/84641/temp/berkshire_new.csv")
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(dateutil.parser.parse)
new_date_range = pd.date_range(df['date'].min(), df['date'].max())
df = df.set_index('date')
df.reindex(new_date_range)
```

Unfortunately this throws the following error which I don't quite understand:

```
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (3, 4825), indices imply (3, 4384)
```

I've tried a dozen variations of this - without any luck. Any help would be much appreciated.

**Edit:**

After investigating this further, it looks like the problem is caused by duplicate indexes. The CSV does contain several entries for each date, which is probably causing the errors.

The question is still relevant though: How can I fill the gaps in between, although there are duplicate entries for each date?

Comment: Which line throws the exception?  Is it already the `read_csv`?

Comment: @Alfe No, the line that throws an error is the one with `reindex`. I've also added more information to the question, because I think the problem is caused by duplicate keys in the CSV.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have duplicates when considering symbol,date,action.

```
In [99]: df.head(10)
Out[99]: 
  symbol                date      change    action
0    FDC 2001-08-15 00:00:00   15.069360       new
1    GPS 2001-08-15 00:00:00   19.653780       new
2    HON 2001-08-15 00:00:00    8.604316       new
3    LIZ 2001-08-15 00:00:00    6.711568       new
4    NKE 2001-08-15 00:00:00   22.686257       new
5    ODP 2001-08-15 00:00:00    5.686902       new
6    OSI 2001-08-15 00:00:00    5.893340       new
7    USB 2001-08-15 00:00:00   15.694478       new
8    NEE 2001-11-15 00:00:00  100.000000       new
9    GPS 2001-11-15 00:00:00  142.522231  increase
```

Create the new date index

```
In [102]: idx = pd.date_range(df.date.min(),df.date.max())

In [103]: idx
Out[103]: 
<class 'pandas.tseries.index.DatetimeIndex'>
[2001-08-15 00:00:00, ..., 2013-08-15 00:00:00]
Length: 4384, Freq: D, Timezone: None
```

This will, group by symbol and action
Then reindex that set to the full dates (idx)
Select out the only remaining column (change)
As now the index is symbol/date

```
In [100]: df.groupby(['symbol','action']).apply(
              lambda x: x.set_index('date').reindex(idx)
                  )['change'].reset_index(level=1).head()

Out[100]: 
                     action  change
symbol                             
ADM    2001-08-15  decrease     NaN
       2001-08-16  decrease     NaN
       2001-08-17  decrease     NaN
       2001-08-18  decrease     NaN
       2001-08-19  decrease     NaN

In [101]: df.groupby(['symbol','action']).apply(lambda x: x.set_index('date').reindex(idx))['change'].reset_index(level=1)
Out[101]: 
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
MultiIndex: 977632 entries, (ADM, 2001-08-15 00:00:00) to (svm, 2013-08-15 00:00:00)
Data columns (total 2 columns):
action    977632  non-null values
change    490  non-null values
dtypes: float64(1), object(1)
```

You can then fill forward or whatever you need. FYI, not sure what you are going to do with this, but this is not a very common type of operation as you have mostly empty data.

Comment: thanks! This is pretty much what I need. Didn't thought that it would be that complicated though :)
I need to set a NaN for the actions as well, but haven't figured out how to do it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having a similar problem at the moment, I think you shouldn't use reindex but something like [asfreq](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.asfreq.html) or [resample](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html).

with them you don't need to create an index, thy will.